# Mobile website viewing vote counts disabled on my own question

Tags: support, mobile-web

In Mobile website when I view **my own** question or answer,
I'm trying to viewing vote counts by clicking on the votes.
I can't click on it and it click on upvote or down vote which I can't do.

Is it by design ? because it's abit annoying to try to click. 
Suggestion: don't allow clicking at all or allow to view negative and positive votes only.

Comment: Which mobile variant?  The Stack Overflow app, the Stack Exchange app, or the mobile website?

Comment: Mobile website only

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Being able to view the vote counts on mobile web was only available for a very short amount of time when mobile web was first made available. It was removed shortly after because "click" precision on a mobile device is not accurate enough to hit the correct thing when there are three somewhat-small buttons all stacked on top of each other. There is no support for viewing the vote counts on the mobile version of the site - you have to use the full site.

Comment: It's really confusing because it may be expect and when clicking you just got error on voting. Can there be a disable notice as graying the count?

Comment: I really don't understand mobile web design. It's not even near my job description, but I just don't get it. Is the average mobile user seen as [Grandma Finds the Internet](https://imgflip.com/s/meme/Grandma-Finds-The-Internet.jpg)? I mean [this is how I browse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKkrU.png), and I have very fat sausage fingers, but I manage to press the number every time when I intend to. Why does _"Make all text bigger and remove all functionality"_ seem to be the credo for mobile web designers?

Comment: @CodeCaster:  Mobile web is different from desktop web due to the screen resolution changes.  There are very good tools available to help you simulate what screen actions are, but in frankness, if you want your site to be usable on mobile, it has to adapt to that environment.  Clicking vote count isn't *that* adaptable for the mobile site.

Comment: @Makoto yeah I know, but why does it look like every mobile site was designed for the lowest common denominator? Why do news sites treat my 1440x2560 6" screen like a 200x300 one? What happened to graceful degradation or progressive enhancement? Everything is supposedly "responsive" these days, but they don't respond to my needs. I disable the mobile web in any way I can, yet Google (when viewing the desktop site on mobile!) links me to m.wikipedia.org when I search something, giving me an atrocious experience. It's infuriating, really. But this might not be the place to discuss that.

Comment: @CodeCaster:  It really isn't, but I'll leave you with this:  mobile web is the new IE6, given how many old and crappy phones are still being used today.  If you're keen, we can talk about this in chat at some later point in time.

Comment: @Makoto thanks, I'll keep that invitation in mind.

Comment: @CodeCaster make sure to upvote all good comments using your mobile device... no zooming in and no using needles.